# Regular expressions in Sublime Text 3

Tags: regex, ubuntu, sublimetext3

I am trying to make a regular expression that replaces the content of the texts in parentheses.

I have used the following regular expression:

```
"([A-Za-z ]*)"
```

But as you can see in the following image does not work:

[image: As you can see this activated the "regular expressions" function.[1]]

Thank you and greetings.

Comment: You need to escape the parentheses - `\([A-Za-z ]*\)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the double quotes from your expression and escape the parentheses:

```
\([A-Za-z ]*\)
```

[image]

**Details**:

- `\(` - a literal `(`
- `[A-Za-z ]*`  - zero or more ASCII letters or spaces
- `\)` - a literal `)`.

The unescaped `(...)` form a *capturing group* that stores a submatch in the memory buffer that can be used later during matching or replacement via backreferences.